# Send model with list to controller via ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a task model:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Useraccount> Useraccounts { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to send a task model via ajax to my controller:

```
function sendForm(projectId, useraccountIds, name, date, description, target) {
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            projectId: projectId,
            useraccounts: useraccountIds,
            name : name,
            dueDate : date,
            description : description
        }),
        success: ajaxOnSuccess,
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Es ist ein Fehler bei der Übertragung aufgetreten.');
        }
    });
}
```

This is working fine but there's a big problem with the useraccounts.
The variable useraccountIds is an integer array but can't be mapped to the ICollection Useraccounts of my task model.

How am I able to create a useraccount object for each id and map it to the useraccounts collection? Those objects don't need more than its id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How am I able to create a useraccount object for each id and map it to
>   the useraccounts collection? Those objects don't need more than its
>   id.

Then you only need to declare it as:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<int> Useraccounts { get; set; }
```

If `Task` is an entity and not a viewmodel then it would be best to write a viewmodel for your Task since you mentioned you won't need other properties from `Useraccount` other than the `Id`.

**UPDATE:**
Build your `Useraccounts` too in javascript:

```
var useraccounts = {
 { Id: value1 },
 { Id: value2 }
};
```

then include it in your post:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    projectId: projectId,
    useraccounts: useraccounts ,
    name : name,
    dueDate : date,
    description : description
}),
```

That won't work if you have dataannotation on your Useraccount model. And if you do then it's a mess as you will have to copy all the required fields of a `Useraccount` to the view, put it in a hidden field (hacky) and send it back to the method.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Task is a real entity model. Unfortunatley we don't use view models to get data from the view to the controller, we just send view models from the controller to the view.
Is there any other approach? A "complex Json object" or something like this?

Comment: You send view model from the controller to the view but not vice versa? That is kindda weird. Anyway, I'll update the answer, check back in a while.

Comment: Yes, I just did exactly the same as you posted some minutes ago and basically it's working.
But my useraccount object is quite complex, there are some more properties which are required (name, email, password) so ModelState.IsValid check fails. :(
I think we have to re-think our design...

Comment: "there are some more properties which are required...so ModelState.IsValid" - that's exactly what I meant in my updated answer. "I think we have to re-think our design" - I humbly suggest so. The basic idea (and the biggest benefit, IMO) of having a viewmodel is to prevent over posting. That means, NOT posting any fields that you won't actually save in your database nor even use in anyway in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll mark your answer as correct.
Are there any documented best practices for the view-model-approach?
I know the asp.net/mvc tutorials but there they don't use view-models to send to the controller-post-methods. They use real entity models only.

Comment: A lot of times, MS tutorials does not involve best practices but shows samples that users can follow easily. [Here's something you can start with](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1014/aspnet-mvc-best-practices/)